# Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): >=2.7.5. react-native

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, react-native

I have create a new project using the command `npx react-native init myProjectName` when I navigate to the project it say

```
Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): >=2.6.10.
```

Here is the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# You may use http://rbenv.org/ or https://rvm.io/ to install and use this version
ruby '>= 2.6.10'

gem 'cocoapods', '>= 1.11.3'
```

I have also installed multiple ruby version with rvm

```
apple@Apples-MacBook-Pro fastVpn % rvm list          
   ruby-2.7.4 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.7.5 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.7.6 [ x86_64 ]
```

but still have same issue

Comment: ```rvm use 2.7.5 --default``` then ```bundle install```

Comment: still have the same issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ruby` method in a `Gemfile` expects a specific Ruby version and cannot handle version constraints like `'>= 2.6.10'`.

Change

```
ruby '>= 2.6.10'
```

to

```
ruby '2.7.5'
```

Comment: that work fines. but in the latest react-native version it was like this ruby '>= 2.6.10'